# Filling in POST parameter variables into a route

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, http-post

I'm currently attempting to make a POST request in Node.js for a GroupMe bot to a route that looks like this:

`/groups/:group_id/members/:membership_id/remove`

where the `hostname = api.groupme.com`

Given that I have the `group_id` and `membership_id` saved in two integer variables, how would I make a HTTP POST request to that route?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try to use the http.request method of the http module?

Comment: You should simple be using path: /groups/23409859825/members/5298895289/remove

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use node's native http module and the request function.

Something like

```
const http = require('http')
const group_id = 5678;
const membership_id = 1234;
http.request({
   host: 'api.groupme.com',
   path: `/groups/${group_id}/members/${membership_id}/remove`,
   method: 'POST'
}, response => {
    ... deal with the response here ...
});
```

will POST to `/groups/5678/members/1234/remove`.

note the backticks in the path to allow the insertion of the variables!